# Fast insertion of rdf triples using redland/c++

Tags: c++, c++11, rdf, redland

I went over the redland documentation and there are some problems I couldn't be certain of solving.

Looking on a c++ side, suppose you generate numerous rdf triples over time for several different graphs, and knowing it is not interested a primary interest to have all graphs in memory:

Is it possible to use redland to perform single/bulk insertions (write into persistent storage) without keeping the graph in memory, and how would you tune such insertions?

If we forget about the querying, what would be a good persistent way of storage: files or databases?

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use redland to perform single/bulk insertions (write into persistent storage) without keeping the graph in memory, and how would you tune such insertions?

Yes. Create a `librdf_storage` object where you want your data stored and pass it to `librdf_new_model()`. Then use any of the API functions such as `librdf_parser_parse_into_model()`to store data in that model and it gets persisted in the storage.

The graph is only kept in memory if the librdf storage module is written that way.

> If we forget about the querying, what would be a good persistent way of storage: files or databases?

The `file` storage is not really for serious business. It keeps the graph in memory and persists to disk by serializing to/from RDF/XML.

Use a database-backed storage such as `mysql` or BDB `hashes`.